# How to make a POST request using Advanced Rest Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning basics of ASP.Net MVC 5. And I want to make a POST request to one of my controller action present in `SecurityController` using `Advanced rest Client`. But I am not able to do so. Please guide  me.

Below is my attempt:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Hello(SampleMV viewModel)
{
    return Content("Hello");
}

public class SampleMV
{
    public int one { get; set; }
    public int two { get; set; }
    public int? three { get; set; }
}
```

Now what are the changes I need to make in my Advanced Rest Client?

Step 1. set request dropdown to `POST`

Step 2. in the raw payload section I added below explicitly:

```
one = 2, two = 3, three = 4  seperated by comma.
```

I am not sure if this is the right way.

Step 3. Do I need to put some content type or any other configuration. Currently, I am getting error as `Resource not found`.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]
**EDIT: Another Attempt**

**[image]**

Comment: The payload is not JSON, on JSON it should be: `{ "one":2, "two":3, "three":4 }`

Comment: Why did you add `/security` in the URL? Is the controller `SecurityController`?

Comment: I have my action in securitycontroller

Comment: @Gusman : I made another attempt. Added it like JSON and changed dropdown to `application/json`

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari : Can see my edit.

Comment: @Gusman : Its working now. Thank you so so much

Comment: @Gusman: If you can out your comment as an answer. It will help some beginner. I will accept the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your payload is malformed, the object definition in JSON should be  `{ "one":2, "two":3, "three":4 }`

Answer (score 4):

404 means you have a routing problem. It's not related to the payload as that doesn't contribute to the route in any way. Assuming this method is `SecurityController.Hello`, and you're utilizing the default route, a request to `/security/hello` should go to the right place. As a result, it may be helpful to include your RouteConfig.cs in your question, as well.

Also, if you're utilizing an `ApiController`, I think action names must follow the convention of starting with the request method. In other words, your `Hello` action needs to be named `PostHello`.

Once you get the routing sorted, the way you have the request body as JSON, now, should work fine. For future reference, "raw" would need to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, i.e. `one=1&two=2&three=3`